# How to Consume WCF Service in SSRS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, reporting-services, webforms

I have to configure WCF Service as Data Source reference in SSRS but did not find its solution yet.
Any help in this regard will be really appreciated!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found two related tutorials, hope it will be useful to you.
[Consuming a WCF Service from an SSRS (RDL) Server Report](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37270/Consuming-a-WCF-Service-from-an-SSRS-RDL-Server-Re)
[WCF Service as DataSource in SSRS](https://srinivasgorantla.blogspot.com/2015/07/wcf-service-as-datasource-in-ssrs.html?m=0)